# char* and char[] with strcat()

Tags: c, string, pointers

My Question is `char *string1` cannot be modified, then why they have syntax like

```
char *strcat(char *string1, const char *string2) ??
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
        const char *p="Everyone";
        char *a="Hello ";
        printf("%s",strcat(a,p));
        return 0;
}
```

Output: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void)
{
        const char *p="Everyone";
        char a[20]="Hello ";
        printf("%s",strcat(a,p));
        return 0;
}
```

Output: Hello Everyone

In snippet 1,char* stores in read-only memory, so we cannot modify(Here the modification is concatenation) I think that's why it shows segmentation fault

but  syntax for `strcat()` is `char *strcat(char *string1, const char *string2)` .

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: What's the problem? In the first example you try to modify a string literal, which leads to undefined behavior. There's really not more to say about it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in `strcat`. The problem is that C90, due to backwards compatibility, decided to type the *string literals* as arrays of non-const characters, but specified that the *behaviour* when attempting to modify the characters in the said arrays *would be undefined*. After all, the entire `const` keyword was introduced in 80s being adopted from **C++**!

Even today, many compilers, like GCC, have a (questionable) option `-fwritable-strings` that makes string literals *modifiable*, just like in some early C compilers.

---

Notice that nothing stops you from writing

```
const char *a = "Hello ";
```

and then the `strcat` would complain loudly.

Answer (score 0):

> My Question is `char *string1` cannot be modified, then why they have syntax like
>
> > ```
> >    char *strcat(char *string1, const char *string2) ??
> > ```

Well, it depends on the argument you pass as the first parameter to the call. It's the requirement of the function and responsibility of the programmer to ensure to pass the first parameter as a pointer to memory which

- can be modified (writable)
- has enough memory to store the concatenated value.

The function signature is fine, it accepts a pointer to a `char` (array, long enough as per requirement).